# Is there a chance to recover the .git/config file?

Tags: windows, git, config

The `.git/config` file has mysteriously disappeared from my working repo.
I have lost my remotes and the smudge/clean filters.

Is there a chance to recover the `.git/config` file?

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Which operating system do you use ?

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with git, git does not have a cache mechanism for any of its content.

You will need to use 3rd party recovery tools.

Try [Piriform's Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva)

Answer (score 0):

`git clone` your remote repository (you could interrupt the process just after the file is created), or do a `git init` in an empty directory and copy the file in your working repository. It should be a good start.

Perhaps you will have to add some remotes or some other info but nothing very important...